# Unable to insert multiple rows to sql table from python

Tags: python, sql, sql-insert, pyodbc

Even though I pass a list as params I am getting the below error while executing the query

```
TypeError: ('Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row', 'HY000')
```

I am trying to pass multiple rows to sql table using `executemany`

Please find my code below and help, I am new to python.

````
query = """INSERT INTO TableTest (Summary) Values (%s)"""
val = [('SPHXNORF2ASW1'),('CHNSIRSDB1USAA'),('NKOLGTPRAVPNVM'),('STAMHO3WANCEG'),('SPHXNORWANCEG1'),('SPHXNORWANCE'),('STAMHO3WANCEG')]
       
     
                 
      
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.executemany(query,val)

conn.commit()   ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, putting a value inside '()' does not make it tuple.
So, this code

```
val = [('SPHXNORF2ASW1'),('CHNSIRSDB1USAA'),('NKOLGTPRAVPNVM'),('STAMHO3WANCEG'),('SPHXNORWANCEG1'),('SPHXNORWANCE'),('STAMHO3WANCEG')]
```

will be converted to

```
['SPHXNORF2ASW1', 'CHNSIRSDB1USAA', 'NKOLGTPRAVPNVM', 'STAMHO3WANCEG', 'SPHXNORWANCEG1', 'SPHXNORWANCE', 'STAMHO3WANCEG']
```

If you want to specify it as a tuple, add a trailing comma like below or use `'[]'` instead of tuple.

Use:

```
val = [('SPHXNORF2ASW1',),('CHNSIRSDB1USAA',),('NKOLGTPRAVPNVM',),('STAMHO3WANCEG',),('SPHXNORWANCEG1',),('SPHXNORWANCE',),('STAMHO3WANCEG',)]
```

Or:

```
[ ['SPHXNORF2ASW1'], ['CHNSIRSDB1USAA'], ['NKOLGTPRAVPNVM'], ['STAMHO3WANCEG'], ['SPHXNORWANCEG1'], ['SPHXNORWANCE'], ['STAMHO3WANCEG']]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing the knowledge you got, it worked for me.

Comment: Good to know it helped you. You can accept it as the answer if the issue was resolved